# What is "AxSHDocVw" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

What is it use and how it can be used.I think its a DLL.But don't know much more.

Answer (score 3):

It is for use as a web browser and also can be used with MSHTML commands to be an HTML Editor

see:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webbrowser.aspx?fid=2148&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=199128&fr=176

Comment: Its very old Richard.Can you have examples that are created in VS.NET 2008.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [web browser component](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000052.html) which you can use to host a browser in your application.